# How multiple Wireless Access Points and multiple hosts interact with each other?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have multiple WAPs which broadcast the same SSID, and a lot of hosts roaming freely between them.

1. When a host is in range of multiple WAPs and send data packets over the air to its currently connected WAP, theoretically the packets shall reach the other WAPs as well. How can they know the packets are not destined for them and drop these packets?
2. When a host sends packets to a WAP, can other hosts sniff the raw data on the air? Assume that they have the WLAN key.

For the 1st question, I guess it has something to do with BSSID of the WAP. But after studying the structure of 802.11 frames, I did not find the BSSID anywhere inside the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a host is in range of multiple WAPs and send data packets over the air to its currently connected WAP, theoretically the packets shall reach the other WAPs as well. How can they know the packets are not destined for them and drop these packets?

The frame headers don't just have the destination host's MAC address; **they do actually have the access point's MAC** (the BSSID). And in "WDS bridging" mode, also known as 4addr mode, there are four address fields allowing *both* access points' MACs to be included.

[image: Snippet of IEEE 802.11-2016 page 638 displaying the address fields]

To quote 802.11-2016:

> **9.2.4.3 Address fields**
>
> **9.2.4.3.1 General**
>
> There are four address fields in the MAC frame format. These fields are used to indicate the basic service set identifier (BSSID), source address (SA), destination address (DA), transmitting STA address (TA), and receiving STA address (RA). Certain frames might not contain some of the address fields.
>
> Certain address field usage is specified by the relative position of the address field (1–4) within the MAC header, independent of the type of address present in that field. For example, receiver address matching is always performed on the contents of the Address 1 field in received frames, and the receiver address of CTS and Ack frames is always obtained from the Address 2 field in the corresponding RTS frame, or from the frame being acknowledged.

You can't see this in a regular tcpdump packet capture, as Wi-Fi by design provides a fully Ethernet-compatible link layer, but you can see it through a "monitor mode" capture which gives you raw 802.11 frames.

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark displaying the three addresses]

Of course, ideally APs within range should be on a different radio frequency so that the packets wouldn't be received at all (and wouldn't cause interference when clients of both APs are trying to transfer data).

> When a host sends packets to a WAP, can other hosts sniff the raw data on the air? Assume that they have the WLAN key.

Depends on the security mode.

- In static WEP, yes.
- In WPA1-PSK and WPA2-PSK, the passphrase isn't directly used as the encryption key – it's used for the key exchange (4-way handshake). Other devices, whether APs or clients, can decrypt packets only if they have the PSK *and* the handshake that was used to produce the key.
- In WPA3-SAE, the new key exchange mechanism should make this impossible even if the PSK is known.
- In WPA-EAP (WPA-Enterprise), this should also be impossible as each client uses a different encryption key, and the key is not actually sent over the air. Rather, the AP receives the key over Ethernet from the RADIUS server, and (at least for PEAP and TTLS) the key itself is derived from a TLS handshake.

Comment: Do hosts use the SSID anywhere in the packet after connected to the WAP? I suspect the SSID is just something the hosts use to connect to the WAP, after that it uses BSSID exclusively. But that means a single WAP broadcasting multiple SSIDs shall have multiple corresponding BSSIDs (just like multiple virtual interfaces facing multiple VLANs), so that it knows which packet belongs to which SSID.